# Exporting to Excel from Sharepoint using PS 2.0

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to navigate to a SharePoint site each morning and click the "Export to Excel" button in the SharePoint ribbon. I tried to bypass it simply by navigating to the website and using the export-csv route, but it does not accomplish the same goal.

Any insight on how to finish this code to click that "Export to Excel" button?

When I right click the "Export to Excel" button on the ribbon and click "Inspect element," I get the following:

```
<IMG style="LEFT: 0px; TOP: -352px" alt="" src="/_layouts/1033/images/formatmap32x32.png" unselectable="on">
```

Here is my starting code:

```
$Url = "website" 

# Invoke Internet Explorer 
$IE = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application; 
$IE.visible = $true; 
$IE.navigate($url); 

Export-CSV "C:\Users\whatever\whatever.csv
```

Comment: Are you saying that the click action is not working on the button? Or that you just don't want to use it? Would you mind making that clear? Thanks!

Comment: I can click it with my mouse and it works just fine...I'm trying to get Powershell to click it when I have it navigate to the website.